# How to load data from web server on ios

Tags: php, ios, webserver

I've been researching on how to load data from a mysql server to my ios device.  Most of the examples I've seen send variables to the server (like username and password) and then retrieve the needed information using POST. In my case, I don't need to send any information to the server, just retrieve.

So my question is, do I need to use POST to grab the information?

Also, I can't seem to find any examples on the php part. How should I code my php file to return all information from a table in my database? Sorry this may sound like a vague question but I can't seem to find any examples.

A big thanks to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:__YOUR URL__];
        NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                  cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                              timeoutInterval:60.0];
        NSURLConnection *connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
        if (connection) {
            self.rssData = [NSMutableData data];   
        } else {   
            NSLog(@"Connection failed");
        }
    }
    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
        [self.rssData setLength:0];
     }

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
        [self.rssData appendData:data];
    }



     - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];            
        NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.rssData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"%@",result);   
        }

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }
```

Hope it help!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! Do you happen to have an example for the php side? I can't seem to wrap my head around how it should be written.

Comment: `NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://php.net/downloads.php"];` and it's work fine

Comment: Thanks but in what way should I write my php method? I have written a query to get the data, what do I do after that? Do I have to assign each variable to POST? Like $_POST["book_name"]?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **GET** to retrieve the data.

As an example:

In .h

```
@interface WSHandler : NSObject <NSURLConnectionDelegate>
{
    NSMutableData *receivedData;
}

- (void)callWebService;
@end
```

in .m:

```
- (void)callWebService
{   

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:WS_URL]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if (connection)
    {
        receivedData = nil;
    }
    else
    {
        DLog(@"Connection could not be established");
    }
}

#pragma mark - NSURLConnection delegate methods
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [receivedData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    if (!receivedData)
        receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:data];
    else
        [receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    DLog(@"***** Connection failed");

    receivedData=nil;
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // do something with the data
    DLog(@"***** Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[receivedData length]);
    DLog(@"***** AS UTF8:%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
}
```